# Save state of ubuntu when switching to windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, operating-systems

I have a pc that runs ubuntu and windows and occasionally I have to switch to windows since things aren't always compatible with ubuntu. Therefore, I must close all open applications and open windows. Any way I can preserve the state of ubuntu when switching to windows so I don't have to reopen all my previously opened applications?

Comment: I have many time using linux and the only way to, I know that it is possible it is save the state using a virtual machine, may i suggest  something in my transition to linux i found many difficulties to adapt whats I was doing at that time for the same reason but whit time i understand there is no anything you can do whit windows there you cant do whit linux you can do a virtual machine no matter which host OS you choose you always can configure shared folders !

Answer (score 1):

Setup hibernation on your Ubuntu install. It will save state to your swap partition/file and Windows will never try to mess with it, when you reboot into Windows.